# Android how to set Media Player (Videoview) on Button click?

Tags: android, button, onclick, media-player, android-videoview

I write a app that plays 3gp videos from url, everything works fine but just can open a video from an activity, that would mean I have to set an activity for each movie I will show in my app, and that would be to many.

I will open my video whit a button click and so that I can write 20 links in a single activity!

Here is my code witch works as a single activity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;
 
public class videoact extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.videoview);
        
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.view1);
        try
        {
         Uri ur = Uri.parse("rtsp://v4.cache4.c.youtube.com/CjgLENy73wIaLwkHCCLABs2fehMYJCAkFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSB3JlbGF0ZWRg7e7u0PeUj8hMDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp");
         vv.setVideoURI(ur);
         vv.setMediaController(mc);
         vv.requestFocus();
         vv.start();
         mc.show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
         System.out.print(e.getMessage() + "error");
        }
       
    }
 
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mp.start();
}
   
}
```

and if I try to make a button in front of it:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;
 
public class videoact extends Activity implements OnPreparedListener{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        Button next1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        next1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
        

//here Eclipse say"The constructor MediaController(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined"
//and gives an error


        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        VideoView vv = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.view1);
        try
        {
         Uri ur = Uri.parse("rtsp://v4.cache4.c.youtube.com/CjgLENy73wIaLwkHCCLABs2fehMYJCAkFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSB3JlbGF0ZWRg7e7u0PeUj8hMDA==/0/0/0/video.3gp");
         vv.setVideoURI(ur);
         vv.setMediaController(mc);
         vv.requestFocus();
         vv.start();
         mc.show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
         System.out.print(e.getMessage() + "error");
        }
       
    }
 
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
mp.start();
}
   
}
```

In the second version I change the set content view to "main"
there are a button from where the button1 should start to play the video!

#### Update:

Maybe I cant explain my self! What I need to do is I have a activity( MainActivity) were I load a layout. In this layout I have the covers of different movies the covers are buttons.
If I pres the cover the media player should start play the code I write before, my problem is the code I write is in a another activity lets call him (Movie1), if i do it this way I have to create for each movie one activity and this is to much I think, lets say it would be more than 40 activities, if you say 40 activities is not much than I have no problem, or just tell me hove to say my activity (MainAcitivity) for example on button click open video from URL file without open Movie1 activity!

I think I have to create a blank MediaPlayer activity where I can say load by button click x this URL with my MediaPlayer activity but I don't know how.